# Eulerian Graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If we have two Eulerian graphs $H = (V,E)$ and $H' = (V, E')$ that are on the same set of $n \geq 5$ vertices and do not share any edges. Is the disjunction of $G$ and $H$ also Eulerian.

Answer (score 1):

There's one quibble with the conclusion here.

Suppose that $H$ is a graph on vertex set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with edges $\{12,13,23\}$ and $H'$ is a graph on the same vertex set with edges $\{45, 46, 56\}$. Then, even though $H$ and $H'$ are not connected, they are Eulerian: all components except one are isolated vertices, and so there is still a closed walk that visits every edge exactly once. However, the union of $H$ and $H'$ is not Eulerian, because you have two $3$-cycles, and can't get from one to the other.

On the other hand, if your definition of an Eulerian graph requires it to be connected, then you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

That proof looks correct to me, and you can even weaken the hypothesis. Instead of both of them having the same exact set of vertices, you can just assume $H$ and $H'$ share at least a single vertex, so that their sum is connected.